# How to take an Excel file and reformatting it automatically

Tags: java

We need to be able to take from one folder format it and save it into another using whatever works. We have searched online and come up with nothing any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/330291/how-to-stop-excel-from-auto-formatting-and-making-it-work-like-a-number-crunchin use this link .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to manipulate MS Office Documents.

There are many examples out there that show how to use it.